# My Centos Server cannot resolve the DNS host name

Tags: centos, iptables, dns

My Server OS: Centos 6.3 x64.

The server `iptables` is:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
```

But I get neither a response issuing

```
ping www.google.com
```

OR

```
curl -I http://www.google.com
```

from the server. Both receive no response!

How to modify my `iptables` rules?

Comment: what's output this command? `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @Babyy see `iptables-save`

Comment: @ikool: please provide output of your `ping` cmd. Your rules allow connect to your machine on ports 22, 80. To check if the ports are open use `nc -v -z host 80`.

Comment: @Babyy cat /etc/resolv.conf
8.8.8.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give many details about your network setup, but assuming that the `iptables` configuration is on host "A" and you tried to `ping` from host "B", then here's the answer.

You configured `iptables` to allow TCP ports 22 and 80. All other traffic is blocked because `iptables` interprets the configuration from the top and you have

```
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
```

set.

ICMP is a different protocol, and you have to explicitly allow it in order to be able to `ping` the machine:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -s 0/0 -d YOUR_IP -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

**EDIT:** your edit in the original question showed that you are trying to access hosts **from** the host you've configured `iptables`. So you have to tell `iptables` to accept packets that are part of an existing connection:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

You should allow udp port 53 for name  resolution and icmp echo for ping test